# What causes this implicit conversion error from type void to List<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics

I have written the following code:

```
public List<Card> DealCards(int numCardsToDeal) {
            return shuffle.RemoveRange(0,numCardsToDeal-1);

        }

private List<Card> shuffle = new List<Card>() // class property deceleration.
```

But it produces the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

I don't understand why. It works when I just return `shuffle`. Why does that fix the problem?

Comment: Maybe because your card class does not implement IEnumerbale Property......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RemoveRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5.aspx) modifies the list and doesn't return anything - hence the `void`. In this it's is different to a lot of list methods that return a new list.

The following code where you remove the cards and then return the list should work:

```
public List<Card> DealCards(int numCardsToDeal)
{
    shuffle.RemoveRange(0,numCardsToDeal-1);
    return shuffle;
}
```

If `shuffle` actually is a global you don't even need to return anything.

Answer (score 1):

The [`RemoveRange` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5.aspx) does not return a value—its return type is `void`. All it does it remove the specified range of elements from the list. It does not return the modified list, or a list containing the removed objects.

Thus, trying to return the result of the `RemoveRange` method produces an error, because you cannot return `void` from a function that is supposed to return a `List<Card>`.

You need to split your code up into two lines:

```
public List<Card> DealCards(int numCardsToDeal)
{
    // First, remove the range of cards from the deck.
    shuffle.RemoveRange(0,numCardsToDeal-1);

    // Then, return the modified list.
    return shuffle;
}
```